# Why does a name change affect functionality?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Recently I was looking for a way to make all pixels in a photo white in python, and I found the following:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('img.png')
imga = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = imga.getdata()

newData = []
for item in datas:
    if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
        newData.append(item)
img.putdata(newData)
img.save("img2.png", "PNG")
```

This does not work. However, when I change lines

```
imga = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = imga.getdata()
```

to:

```
img = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = img.getdata()
```

the code works, and all white pixels become transparent. I've rerun the code multiple times using the first, then second lines, and the result is consistent. Why is this?

Comment: Assuming you changed nothing else, then in the second case you're overwriting the existing variable named `img`, which is used later in the program.

Comment: In the original code, `img.putdata(newData)` and `img.save("img2.png", "PNG")` still refer to `img` as returned by `img = Image.open('img.png')`, and after the change they refer to `img` as returned by `img = img.convert("RGBA")`. I don't know the semantics of PIL to explain why that makes a difference.

Comment: What would be the point of making all pixels white? Just make a new white image the same size. If you are treating images as list of pixels you have probably already gone wrong, you will find PIL functions coded in C and Numpy operations MUCH faster and simpler. What are you really trying to do?